# Как засунуть HashMap в JobParameters

Tags: java, springbatch

В Spring Batch я создаю

```
JobParametersBuilder jobBuilder= new JobParametersBuilder();
            jobBuilder.addString("filename", "file1");
            jobBuilder.addString("studentName","Piter");
            ...
            JobParameters jobParameters =jobBuilder.toJobParameters();
```

Который потом извлекаю из него в ItemWriter

```
final Map<String, JobParameter> parameters =
    stepExecution.getJobExecution().getJobParameters().getParameters();
String filename = parameters.get("filename").toString();
```

Все было хорошо пока мне не понадобилось добавить

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>:
```

добавил вот так:

```
final JobParametersBuilder properties= new JobParametersBuilder();
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
  paramsProp.addString(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
jobBuilder.addJobParameters(paramsProp.toJobParameters())
```

Вот только теперь как это все извлечь с учетом моих строковых полей?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не усложняйте жизнь. Сделайте просто, добавьте в название ключа индикатор отдельного объекта и также продолжайте вставлять в `jobBuilder`

```
Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();

for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : properties.entrySet()) {
  jobBuilder.addString("$properties_" + entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

при считывании проверьте содержит ли ключ этот индикатор `"$properties_"`, удаляете его и создаете ваш

```
   Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
```

обратно из этих ключей.

Другой вариант

```
   Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
```

переведите [JSONObject](https://www.baeldung.com/java-org-json)

```
   JSONObject propertiesJson = new JSONObject(properties);
   jobBuilder.addString("$properties", propertiesJson.toString());
```

обратно также просто, переводите в `JSONObject` и конвертируете в `HashMap`